# How To Remove the root element of json through XLT Transform

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I have an xml that I would like to transform and pass to an API but the transformation I am making has too many nested object and would like to remove the blocks at start to a json that would look like so ;

```
      {
"Body" : [

{
"Code" : "HOT", 
"Name" : "SIDE", 
"Type" : "AADULT", 
"Sec" : "MSec", 
"ardge" : "Adult", 
"Nder" : "F", 
"TBC" : "21", 
"BO" : "14", 
"DBOC" : "0", 
"LBC" : "5", 
"AB" : "2"
}, 

{
"Code" : "HOT", 
"Name" : "DARS", 
"Type" : "AADULT", 
"Sec" : "MSec", 
"ardge" : "OADULT", 
"Nder" : "U", 
"TBC" : "20", 
"BO" : "16", 
"DBOC" : "0", 
"LBC" : "2", 
"AB" : "2"
}
]
"Code" : "HOT", 
"Date" : "2017-12-08 11:22:34.658", 
}
```

here is the original xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
      <Code>HOT</Code>
      <Date>2017-12-08 11:22:34.658</Date>
   <Body>
      <Code>HOT</Code>
      <Name>SIDE</Name>
      <Type>AADULT</Type>
      <Sec>MSec</Sec>
      <ardge>Adult</ardge>
      <Nder>F</Nder>
      <TBC>21</TBC>
      <BO>14</BO>
      <DBOC>0</DBOC>
      <LBC>5</LBC>
      <AB>2</AB>
   </Body>
   <Body>
      <Code>HOT</Code>
      <Name>DARS</Name>
      <Type>AADULT</Type>
      <Sec>MSec</Sec>
      <ardge>OADULT</ardge>
      <Nder>U</Nder>
      <TBC>20</TBC>
      <BO>16</BO>
      <DBOC>0</DBOC>
      <LBC>2</LBC>
      <AB>2</AB>
   </Body>
</Message>
```

and here is the XLT I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*[node()]">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="detect" />
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="detect">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current()) and name(following-sibling::*[1]) != name(current())">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
     <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*[name() != name(current())]) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current())">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
                    <xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*) = name(current())">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][name() = name(current())]">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>" : [</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" /><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) > 0 or count(@*) > 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) = 0">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:apply-templates select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="obj-content">
     <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="attr" />
            <xsl:if test="count(@*) &gt; 0 and (count(child::*) &gt; 0 or text())">, </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" mode="detect" />
            <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and not(@*)">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and @*">
                <xsl:text>"text" : "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="attr">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node/@TEXT | text()" name="removeBreaks">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&#xA;'))"><xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($pText, '&#xD;&#xA;'), ' ')"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="removeBreaks">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&#xD;&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and here is what I am getting at present

```
{
"Message" : 
{
"Code" : "HOT", 
"Date" : "2017-12-08 11:22:34.658", 
"Body" : [

{
"Code" : "HOT", 
"Name" : "SIDE", 
"Type" : "AADULT", 
"Sec" : "MSec", 
"ardge" : "Adult", 
"Nder" : "F", 
"TBC" : "21", 
"BO" : "14", 
"DBOC" : "0", 
"LBC" : "5", 
"AB" : "2"
}, 

{
"Code" : "HOT", 
"Name" : "DARS", 
"Type" : "AADULT", 
"Sec" : "MSec", 
"ardge" : "OADULT", 
"Nder" : "U", 
"TBC" : "20", 
"BO" : "16", 
"DBOC" : "0", 
"LBC" : "2", 
"AB" : "2"
}
]}
}
```

Comment: Actually, I see that you're trying to write a generic XML-to-JSON converter, whereas the answer I've given is specific to your particular XML. Doing generic XML to JSON conversion that can handle any XML is really quite difficult, and the hard part is specifying it rather than coding it. You certainly can't specify it with one example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making it much too complicated. Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="quot">"</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>{&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Message">
    <xsl:text>"Body" : [</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Body"/>
    <xsl:text>],&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Body)]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Body" priority="2">
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,&#xa;</xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Body/* | Message/*" priority="1">
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,&#xa;</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quot, name(), $quot, ':', $quot, string(.), $quot)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks you but I would like to use it for different kinds of xml doc is it possible if yes please  can you direct me where i can learn to do it my self with an example if possible thanks again

Comment: You'll need to start by deciding and defining what to do with attributes, child repeating and non-repeating child elements, mixed content, etc. As I say, the general problem is not easy: but design it before you start coding it.

Comment: is it possible to change that generic xslt to produce generic xml like so    `{
"Code" : "HOT", 
"Date" : "2017-12-08 11:22:34.658", 
"Body" : [

{
"Code" : "HOT", 
"Name" : "SIDE", 
"Type" : "AADULT", 
"Sec" : "MSec", 
"ardge" : "Adult", 
"Nder" : "F", 
"TBC" : "21", 
"BO" : "14", 
"DBOC" : "0", 
"LBC" : "5", 
"AB" : "2"
}, 

{
"Code" : "HOT", 
"Name" : "DARS", 
"Type" : "AADULT", 
"Sec" : "MSec", 
"ardge" : "OADULT", 
"Nder" : "U", 
"TBC" : "20", 
"BO" : "16", 
"DBOC" : "0", 
"LBC" : "2", 
"AB" : "2"
}
]}`

Comment: Asking supplementary questions is best done by adding to the original question, or by raising a completely new question. Doing it in comments runs the risk (as here) of abbreviating it to the point of incomprehensibility.